# Can I use JS .offsetHeight result in equation to style child element?

Tags: javascript

Thanks for reading this.

I'm trying to obtain the .offsetHeight of a parent element, so that I can use it to automatically adjust the margin of a child element to align things properly.

Is it possible to apply a result from .offsetHeight into an equation?

Thank you!

Comment: It's possible to use *any* value in an expression. If you post the actual code that's causing you problems, you'll get more directly useful help.

Comment: You should be using CSS to align things properly

Comment: document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop = var "margin";
I feel like my problem may be that I'm trying to use a variable to style another object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `.parentElement.offsetHeight`

E.G:

```
document.getElementById('post-form').parentElement.offsetHeight;
```